# Bulk percentile calculation in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find the best way to calculate percentiles for a dataset in bulk on Postgres, returning both the percentile and the value.

`generate_series()` plus `percentile_cont()` and lateral join will work, though this can be very slow with many percentiles, as percentile_cont() is called for each item in the series:

```
select percentile, value
from generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) as percentile,
lateral (select percentile_cont(percentile) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIZE) 
  as value from mytable
) values
```

This is much faster but doesn't return the percentile corresponding to each value:

```
select unnest(
percentile_cont(
    (select array_agg(s) from generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) as s)
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIZE))
from mytable
```

And trying to join that one with a second `generate_series()` seems to require an ugly hack to get a column to join on:

```
select percentile, value
from (select row_number() OVER () as rownum, value
    from (select unnest(
        percentile_cont(
            (select array_agg(s) from generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) as s)
        ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIZE)) as value
        from mytable) s2
    ) s3
join (select row_number() OVER () as rownum, percentile
    from (select generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) as percentile) s) p
    on p.rownum = s3.rownum
```

Or taking another approach, `ntiles()` makes for a cleaner query, but values don't quite match with `percentile_cont()`. (Maybe they'd match with `percentile_disc()`?) And this is about half as fast as 2nd/3rd queries above.

```
select ((nt-1)/5::float) as percentile,  min(size) as value
from (select size, ntile(6) over (order by size) as nt
   from mytable
 ) as dt
group by nt
order by nt asc
```

I've gotten this far, but it's still not quite right, and something tells me there's a clean, performant approach out there. Any thoughts on how to improve on these?

EDIT: modifying Sven's answer slightly to return named columns:

```
SELECT unnest(
  (select array_agg(fraction) from generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) AS fraction)
) as percentile,
unnest(
  (select percentile_cont((select array_agg(s) from generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) as s)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIZE) FROM mytable)
) as value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should get you both the percentile and the value

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(
  (select array_agg(fraction) from generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) AS fraction),
  (select percentile_cont((select array_agg(s) from generate_series(0, 1, 0.2) as s)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIZE) FROM mytable)
);
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't think to try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as @Sven Klemm, but broken down using `with` blocks:

```
WITH serie as (
  SELECT array_agg(gs) as v 
  FROM generate_series(0, 1, 0.1) as gs
),
percentiles as (
  SELECT
    percentile_cont((select v from serie)) 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "SIZE") as p
  FROM mytable
)

SELECT 
  unnest(s.v) * 100 as percentile, 
  unnest(p.p) as value
FROM percentiles p, serie s
```

Which gives something like this:

```
 percentile | value
------------+-------
          0 |   8.9
       10.0 | 18.27
       20.0 | 22.16
       30.0 | 24.45
       40.0 | 30.36
       50.0 | 38.05
       60.0 | 43.06
       70.0 | 50.33
       80.0 | 60.06
       90.0 |  61.7
      100.0 |  76.1
```